# How can I allow users to get paid directly with stripe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, stripe-payments, marketplace

I've looked at stripe connect and it forces each user to impute their Social Security number and etc. just so they accept payments for a item they want to sell.

Is there a less painless method where users can sell something on my site, receive monies, and buy from other users?

I tried using stripe alone and it pays me directly. Problem is I want user to sign up, sell something on the site, and get paid. I'm not sure how this can be done without having each user impute social security numbers, tax id, and other personal information if all they want to sell is a pen.

Comment: hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. You've asked a really broad question. Stack Overflow works best for specific, technical questions  that have a "right answer" - or help debugging a specific problem in actual code. A question like this will generally elicit discussion and differing opinions. In the past such discussion often degraded into flame wars that tore apart our community, so now we tend to avoid allowing people to ask these kinds of questions. I'd recommend starting by asking stripe. then trying your local user-group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For financial compliance reasons (know your customer laws, anti-money laundering stuff), as well as protecting you from chargebacks and refunds, you'd have to use Stripe Connect and either Standalone or Managed Accounts. Unfortunately this means you'll have to collect certain information from the user like their bank account, date of birth, last 4 of their social, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can using their Transfers API, but you need to be in the US and so do they.  https://stripe.com/blog/send-payouts-with-stripe

Comment: The Recipients / Transfers functionality has been deprecated and moving forward you'd have to use Stripe Connect

Comment: @MatthewArkin do you have any tutorial or solution for that?